# Sum different ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of sheets in a workbook named SomethingA - Resources
                                           SomethingB - Resources
                                           SomethingC - Resources
                                           etc...................

I am trying to sum a specific range inside every one of these sheets which will change variable before the dash in the name and the amount of sheet will change. I would like the sum to appear in a sheet called "Resources" which i the first sheet in the workbook. My code so far:

```
Sub sumdata1()

  For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sht.Name Like "- Resources*" Then
          For Each cell In Range("G11:G46")
            Sheets("Resources").Range(cell.Address) = Sheets("Resources").Range(cell.Address) + Sheets(i).Range(cell.Address)
          Next cell
          End If
        Next
        End Sub
```

Could appreciate some help.
Be safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:

```
Sub sumdata1()

    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name Like "- Resources*" Then
            For Each cell In Sht.Range("G11:G46")
                addy = cell.Address
                Sheets("Resources").Range(addy) = Sheets("Resources").Range(addy) + cell.Value
            Next cell
        End If
    Next Sht
End Sub
```

You may need to modify the ***LIKE*** statement.

Comment: Wonderful thanks for changing the  syntax I have changed the the Like to be -Resources instead of - Resources. Be safe, thanks.